# Adding to, and highlighting, Q&A link to primary election (candidates) page

Tags: discussion, election

I assume that many not so regular users come to the election page by following a notification on top of the user interface. Hence, they might miss the Q&A that, at the time of this writing, 6 candidates have taken the time to fill out.

When I look at the votes on the Q&A page, and those on the primary for related candidates, there seems to be very little correlation...but I think there should be. Some users left truly excellent answers in excruciating detail; I (personally) was less impressed with others (you might disagree). It made *me* change some votes.

Making it easier for everyone, in particular non-meta regulars, to find the Q&A, might help to make the two pages match up a bit more, which I think would be in the site's and its users' interest. I assume I could edit a link in (could I?), but, given my reasonably low reputation and 99% inactive status, I think I should not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a bold link **The candidates answer your questions** on the election page. However,  it leads to the entire Questionnaire thread, which is quite long already and is going to get longer.

I think the candidates' responses would get more attention if they were linked **individually** from each nomination post. Something like this was done in recent [Server Fault election](https://serverfault.com/election/4?tab=primary): every nomination had a bold link at the top, separated from the rest by horizontal line `---`:

> [image: example]

These links are more convenient (if they lead  directly to an answer, as they should) and  are more likely to be followed by voters than the link listed among others in the section on election rules.

Ordinary users can't edit the nominations, for obvious reasons. I hope the candidates (or SE staff) will edit in something like that.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I don't like the formulation though at all - I'd prefer a clear 'candidate answers to Q&A' or such. As *I* didn't ask any questions (I realize 'your' is ambiguous in English), I honestly expected a chat room or similar...if I even noticed it as the link is a bit TLDR. Hence, I'd put it much closer to the top. That said, following your suggestion would probably be better as long as one also adds something to the sort of "candidate has not answered election Q&A so far," as applicable. Yes, it's voluntary; but not finding time or inclination to do so is telling too.

Comment: It's all manual - I was planning to put this off until the field was narrowed to 10. Because I'm lazy. But since you had to go & call me out here, I've done it now - I'll update them as folks add answers and I get around to it.